# Estimating difference smooth effects for each level of a factor - WHY?

Tags: r, interaction, generalized-additive-model, smoothing, mgcv

I am wondering why you would want to use a by variable smooth `s(time, by= x)`? (time is non-linear hence why I am using [GAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model)s)

I am using GAMs to explore if my response $y$ changes over $x$ or some other categorical factor. Furthermore, if $y$ changes over on $x$, have these differences changed over time?

Also, if I have an interaction between $x$ and $z$, what would be the reasons for me including this interaction in the `by = argument` over time as `s(time, by= interaction(x,z))`?

How do you assess if you need to have different smooths/curves for an interaction?

Any help is appreciated, I am new to GAMs!

Comment: Welcome to CV elaine!

Comment: `s(time, by= x)` is a very general form of interaction.  Say you are modeling the development of some (measurement) for a disease with time, and you have reason to believe this time development is different for men and women. Otherwise, maybe ask for your real applied problem!

Comment: Hi kjetil! Thanks for your answer. So if I see an interaction between Gender and some other categorical variable ie ethnicity. Would I then fit the smooth s(Year, by= interaction(Gender, ethnicity)) if I had reason to believe that this interaction changed over time? Thanks!

Comment: @elaine: At least that might be a starting point. Maybe ask your real, applied proble with more contextual information.